# client side onkeyup in aspx control

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a javascript call in a text box as shown bellow

```
<asp:TextBox ID='Textbox1' runat='server'></asp:TextBox>
```

I need to make the user input in such a way that user cannot put more than 9 digit before point and 9 digits after point.
For example 123456789.123456789 this is the maximum length that a user can enter. I need to do it in keypress or keyup event. Please help me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the  or the AJAX Control Toolkit Masked Edit Extender?
For the first, your regular expression would look like this: `^\d{1,9}(\.{1,9})?$`. You apply it like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID='Textbox1' runat='server'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Textbox1" 
     ErrorMessage="Invalid format" ValidationExpression="^\d{1,9}(\.{1,9})?$" 
     SetFocusOnError="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to do that.

#### Syntax:

```
$('#textboxID').on('KeyUp',function({
    // Validation Logic
}));
```

But I would suggest using KeyPress event instead of KeyUp event. Following is the case that might sneak if you use KeyUp

#### Case:

User has Input *123456789* and when he presses 10th key, textbox will show *1234567890*.
Once the keyUp is triggered, the validation will trigger and the text wil be reverted to *123456789*.
Though it will appear for a fraction of time, its better to be proactive than reactive.

#### References:

- [KeyUp API](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)
- [KeyPress API](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)
- [On Events API](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [For only numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Beside the JQuery to make sure that only 9 chars are in that text box you can do this

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="9"></asp:TextBox>
```

May not be the answer but it is an alternative which in my opinion is a little easier.

Comment: As @Riki has mentioned he wants max 9 digits on both sides of decimal, max length will not solve issue. You can set it to 19 but still it will not help.